# How can I extract the data from a corrupted .docx file?

Tags: word-documents, unzip

My girlfriend's .docx file corrupted and I'm trying to recover the text from it. I learned that .docx is essentially a zip file that contains folders and bunch of .xml files (and one of them contains document text). I following command on Ubuntu 10.10 to unzip the archive:

```
unzip portfolio.docx -d file-dir
```

The result I got is:

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found. Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of multi-part archive. In the latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on the last disk(s) of this archieve.
unzip: cannot find zipfile directory in one of portfolio.docx or portfolio.docx.zip, and cannot find portfolio.docx.ZIP, period.
```

On Windows 8.1 I tried WinZip, 7zip, WinRar and Zip2Fix but without any luck.

The file weights nearly 20Kb so I know there is some content inside. Is there any way to **force unzip**?

Answer (score 5):

Run this:

```
cp portfolio.docx portfolio.zip
```

Or just rename `portfolio.docx` to `portfolio.zip`, and you should be able to open the resultant `portfolio.zip` file with Archive Manager, and extract them.

**Edit:** I just ran a quick check, the files are likely to be in `word/document.xml` or `docProps/core.xml` in the extracted folder.

**Another Edit:** If the resultant zip file is corrupted, look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/23290/terminal-tool-linux-for-repair-corrupted-zip-files).

Comment: I renamed the file to portfolio.zip and opened it with Archive Manager but I still got an error. I tried to uzip the newly created file from command line but again I got exactly the same error as the one I described above. The second command doesn't work either. It says "portfolio.docx: command not found"

Comment: Yes, the file I need is in word/document.xml. That's all I need.

Comment: The second command was a guess - just checked and it would not of produced much anyway. If the first does not work, it is because the file is corrupted... There are millions of ways to try and repair extracted zip files, but they are genrally fairly expesive, and do not always work... - e.g. http://www.techradar.com/news/software/how-to-repair-a-broken-zip-file-986146

Comment: Oh, a few free Unix commands to repair zip's are listed [here](http://superuser.com/questions/23290/terminal-tool-linux-for-repair-corrupted-zip-files)

Comment: I tried all of those Windows programs and none of them fixed my problem. I run the `zip -FF portfolio.zip --out new.zip` and I got output `Is this a single-disk archive`. I said yes and it gave me `zip warning: zip file empty`

Comment: Try answering no, because I don't think it would be a single-disk archive - also try with just `-F` first, then `-FF` *(for more info, run `man zip`)*. Did the other suggested command work? - `unzip -vt file.zip`.

Comment: @MatthewC Why are you trying to use the command line? I used Archive Manger and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Seth I used archive manager and it also worked fine - but I did not try it on a corrupted zip....

Comment: I tried using Archive Manager. I uploaded the file so you can see it yourself. http://www.filedropper.com/corrupted

Comment: Ah, I see. I forgot it was corrupted. Have you tried opening it in MS Word? It can sometimes fix this.